# How to change the Nox Player IMEI or device model?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, android-uiautomator, nox

i am looking for a method to change Nox Playes IMEI or device model, it have this setting in settings.

I thinking about changing it through the pyautogui, i tried adb, but none of the commands worked.
How i can change it through the api, or python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by installing memu player.